# How to implement Compose Navigation Arguments

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm practicing Jetpack compose navigation, currently I'm stuck at passing arguments, so the correct information can be displayed when clicked.

I'm trying to navigate *from* this Destination, MenuScreen;

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(onHomeCardClick: () -> Unit) {
    HomeContentScreen(onHomeCardClick = onHomeCardClick)
}

@Composable
fun HomeContentScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onHomeCardClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Column(
        modifier
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .padding(vertical = 16.dp)) {
        HomeQuote()
       
   ....
    }
}
```

To this destination, MenuInfoScreen;

```
@Composable
fun HomeInfoScreen(){
    WelcomeText()
    HomeInfoDetails()
}

@Composable
fun WelcomeText() {
    Text(
        text = "Welcome, to Home Information",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 12.dp, vertical = 18.dp)
    )
}

@Composable
fun HomeInfoDetails(
    homeInfo: HomeInfo
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape),
        elevation = 10.dp,
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = homeInfo.homeInfoImageId),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(topEnd = 4.dp, bottomEnd = 4.dp)),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            Text(
                text = homeInfo.title,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            Text(
                text = homeInfo.description,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the model I'm trying to follow, HomeInfoModel;

```
object HomeInfoModel {
        

    val homeInfoModelList = listOf(
        
        HomeInfo(
            id = 1,
            title = "Monty",
            sex = "Male",
            age = 14,
            description = "Monty enjoys chicken treats and cuddling while watching Seinfeld.",
            homeInfoImageId = R.drawable.ab1_inversions
        ),
       .....
    )
}
```

Here's the my NavHost;

```
NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Home.route,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        // builder parameter will be defined here as the graph

        composable(route = Home.route) {
            HomeScreen(
                onHomeCardClick = {}
            )
        }
        ....
        composable(route = HomeInfoDestination.route) {
            HomeInfoScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

And my Destinations file;

```
object Home : KetoDestination {
    override val route = "home"
}

....
object HomeInfoDestination : KetoDestination{
    override val route = "homeInfo"

}
```

I know this is a lot and I'm a bit off, but please I've been stuck here for more than a week now. Any little information willl surely come handy.
And Of Course very much appreciated.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should extract the arguments from the NavBackStackEntry that is available in the lambda of the composable() function.

You can read more in the official android docs https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args